# Implicitly wrapping C++ functionality in an Objective-C instance

Tags: c++, objective-c

Is it possoble to proxy a C++ object with an Objective-C wrapper, without the necessity of implementing all of the properties and methods of the cpp object on the objc side? What I am looking for is something more generic that I am sure will work for every object.

```
MyObjCWrapper *obj = [[MyObjCWrapper alloc] initWithCppObj: myCppObj];

[MyObjCWrapper aCppObjMethod ]; //calling a method not explicitly defined in the ObjCWarapper
```

Inheritance would be no go. Inheriting from a C++ class is impossible AFAIK.

One certain way would be by using reflection but it is not necessarily the fastest one. What else? Delegation? I am not so familiar with it, although I know the general principle.

The best approach would be having a "prototype" mechanism like in JavaScript. In this way, one could simply attach the C++ instance on the prototype of the Objective-C one, but would that work?. I suppose there'd be issues with overloading the [] operator, as well as supplying the prototype with the proper "self" context.

So what can I do?

Comment: Can I ask why you need to wrap the C++ object in an Objective-C object rather than using the C++ object directly?

Comment: I use a generator script which produces vanilla C++ from a metalanguage. I need Objective-C stuff for Cocoa. I am planning if possible, to use my metalang for extending and interacting with Cocoa components

Comment: [Objective-C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C.2B.2B)?

Comment: Technically, I should not even have to touch the low level, as my metalanguages produces the C++ for me. Think about it in that way

Comment: 1<->1 wrappers in either direction between these two languages is rarely a good design -- typically, you just provide a higher level or minimal abstraction over the C++ innards, where most of the work happens when your foundation is in C++ to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's not possible.

Point being, Objective-C is very dynamic, whereas C++ is more of a static language. While you can call an Objective-C method that hasn't been defined, and even intercept that call at runtime to handle it (commonly done for proxy objects that forward the call somewhere else), the information about what was called is more like a "string" (not technically a string, but similar) with the name of the method. You can't resolve this to a C++ method call at runtime, unless you already have a list to do the mapping. And that doesn't even take the parameters into account.

In addition, you can't hope to maybe use macros to hide this, since Objective-C syntax isn't really 'macro compatible': to some extent you can always replace function calls with macro calls to try and add additional hidden parameters or something similar (although in C++ this doesn't work with methods...), but you can't do this for an Objective-C call since it has a completely different syntax.

EDIT: "not possible, unless you write a suitable preprocessor to read the C++ and create suitable Objective-C code". That's always possible, of course. But also a lot of work, considering that C++ isn't the most trivial language on the planet.

Comment: Well, I was thinking that if operator overloading were possible, I could overload the [] operator to apply some reflection magic on the cpp instance, and determine if such a method exists on it. If it does simply pass it the list of params, if not, throw a "methodNotFoundException" or sth